# Text around boxed/framed equation

Tags: tcolorbox, wrapfigure, empheq

I want the text closer to my equations, but the equations jump down a line. The equation box also insists on centring itself instead of sticking to the margin.

Is there a way to automatically adapt the `wrapfigure` to the `tcolorbox`/`empheq`, align the box all the way to the margin, and bring the text closer?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\tcbset{enhanced,boxrule=0.8pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,lifted shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{2mm}{0.1mm}{gray!60}}
\newtcbox{\eqbox}[2]{nobeforeafter,math upper,colback=#1,colframe=#2}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}



\begin{document}

\section{Electric Power}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{10.2em}
\begin{empheq}[box=\eqbox{green!70!blue}{green!50!black},box align=right]{equation*}
    P = \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{empheq}
\end{wrapfigure}

\blindtext

\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{10em}
\begin{empheq}[box=\eqbox{red!20}{red!40},box align=right]{equation*}
    P = \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{empheq}
\end{wrapfigure}

\blindtext

\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{l}{10em}
\begin{empheq}[box=\eqbox{red!20}{red!40},box align=right]{equation*}
    P = \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{empheq}
\end{wrapfigure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is the `box align` key defined?

Answer (score 3):

It is much easier to adjust with the `\InsertBoxR` command from the plain TeX macro package `insbox`. This command  takes two mandatory arguments: the number of lines unshortened in the following paragraph before the box is inserted, and the inserted box, and an optional argument, the number of supplementary shorter lines, in case TeX calculates erroneously the number of shorter lines. Using `equation*` is not necessary here – I replaced it with a simple `$\displaystyle ... $`. Last, I loaded `esdiff` to have a simpler typing od (partial or not) derivatives:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\tcbset{enhanced,boxrule=0.8pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,lifted shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{2mm}{0.1mm}{gray!60}}
\newtcbox{\eqbox}[2]{nobeforeafter,math upper,colback=#1,colframe=#2}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}

\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\section{Electric Power}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

\InsertBoxR{0}{\eqbox{green!70!blue}{green!50!black}{\displaystyle P = \diff{w}{t}}}
\blindtext

\InsertBoxR{3}{\eqbox{red!20}{red!40}{\displaystyle P = \diff{w}{t}}}
\blindtext

\InsertBoxR{0}{\eqbox{red!20}{red!40}{\displaystyle P = \diff{w}{t}}}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Forgot to respond: Great work! I've been using this for my equations now, but is it possible to also use it with TikZ figures? Is this possibly fuel for a new question?

Comment: I think it should work: as it is a plain TeX macro there are not so many contra-indications (one is that the box inserted won't float, so if you want a caption, you'll have to put it in a `\parbox` and use `\captionof`). I even was able to make it work  in the neighbourhood of lists, which `wrapfigure` cannot. So, I would advise to try it with TikZ, and ask another question if you have any problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that you use `empheq`, which is great for adding fancy stuff to AMS equation environments. It is, however, less so for `wrapfigure`s because equations have an indent, are centered etc. So I would recommend to switch gears and box an inline equation. This can be done using the `tcolorbox` you defined. The following provides you with an environment that does that. It measures the width and height of the equation, and builds the `wrapfigure` accordingly, taking into account some grace distances that are stored in `/eqrwapbox/xsep` and `/eqrwapbox/ysep`, respectively to make it more convenient for you to change them when needed. The resulting environment is called `InlayEq`, and an example for its usage is

```
\begin{InlayEq}{red!20}{red!40}
P = \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{InlayEq}
```

This is the corresponding MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\tcbset{enhanced,boxrule=0.8pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,lifted
shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{2mm}{0.1mm}{gray!60},}
\newtcbox{\eqbox}[2]{nobeforeafter,math upper,colback=#1,colframe=#2}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}

\usepackage{environ}
\newbox\EqSaveBox
\pgfkeys{/eqrwapbox/.cd,xsep/.initial=0.4em,ysep/.initial=1ex}
\NewEnviron{InlayEq}[3][r]{\begin{lrbox}{\EqSaveBox}
\eqbox{#2}{#3}{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\BODY}}%
\end{lrbox}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywd}{\the\wd\EqSaveBox+\pgfkeysvalueof{/eqrwapbox/xsep}}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myln}{(\the\ht\EqSaveBox+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/eqrwapbox/ysep})/12}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myrest}{(\myln*12pt-\the\ht\EqSaveBox)}%
\edef\temp{\noexpand\wrapfigure[\myln]{#1}{\mywd pt}}%
\temp
\vspace*{\myrest pt}%
\hfill\usebox\EqSaveBox
\endwrapfigure}

\begin{document}

\section{Electric Power}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.


\begin{InlayEq}{green!70!blue}{green!50!black}
P = \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{InlayEq}

\blindtext

\blindtext


\begin{InlayEq}{red!20}{red!40}
P = \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{InlayEq}

\blindtext

\begin{InlayEq}[l]{red!20}{red!40}
P = \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{InlayEq}

\noindent
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

It does not solve the issue with page breaks because this is an inherent issue of `wrapfig` which, to the best of my knowledge, has no solution. Yet I think the other points are all taken care of.

Comment: Note: I am kept `wrapfig` because it works better with e.g. `enumerate` environments. AFAIK none of `wrapfig`, `parpic` or `insbox` is perfect, but generally according to my experience `wrapfig` is advantageous. I also use `parpic`, but have more or less given up on `insbox`.