# Insbox with TikZ or figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, insbox

So, using `input{insbox}` has worked fine with `equation`s, `tcolorbox`es, and even plain text. What's not working, however, is `tikzpicture`s, or `figure`s with `tikzpicture`s.

1. I've tried with a `figure` containing a `tikzpicture`:

```
\InsertBoxL{0}{
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.25in,y=.25in]

        \draw [<-, thick] (0, 4.2) coordinate (Yin) node [above] {$y$}
                       -- (0, 0.0)
                       -- (0,-1.2) coordinate (Yout);
        \draw [->, thick] (-1.5,0) coordinate (Xin)
                       -- ( 0.0,0)
                       -- ( 4.5,0) coordinate (Xout) node [right] {$x$};

        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (1.8, 0.9) node [midway,below] {$\Delta x$};
        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (2.8, 1.4) node [midway,right] {$\Delta y$};

        \draw [domain=-1:4,variable=\x,red,thick] plot({\x},{(\x)/2});

    \end{tikzpicture}
  % \caption{Linear function}
    \label{fig:linear}
    \end{figure}
}
```

2. And just a `tikzpicture`:

```
\InsertBoxL{0}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.25in,y=.25in]

        \draw [<-, thick] (0, 4.2) coordinate (Yin) node [above] {$y$}
                       -- (0, 0.0)
                       -- (0,-1.2) coordinate (Yout);
        \draw [->, thick] (-1.5,0) coordinate (Xin)
                       -- ( 0.0,0)
                       -- ( 4.5,0) coordinate (Xout) node [right] {$x$};

        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (1.8, 0.9) node [midway,below] {$\Delta x$};
        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (2.8, 1.4) node [midway,right] {$\Delta y$};

        \draw [domain=-1:4,variable=\x,red,thick] plot({\x},{(\x)/2});

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

3. It even won't work with just plain text inside a `figure`:

```
\InsertBoxL{0}{
    \begin{figure}What does NOT seem to work is this\end{figure}
}

Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here.
```

---

MWE with plain text that *does* works:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxL{0}{
    \textbf{What does seem to work is this}
}

Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. Text goes here. 

\end{document}
```

---

MWE with `TikZ` in a `figure` that *doesn't* work:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxL{0}{
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.25in,y=.25in]

        \draw [<-, thick] (0, 4.2) coordinate (Yin) node [above] {$y$}
                       -- (0, 0.0)
                       -- (0,-1.2) coordinate (Yout);
        \draw [->, thick] (-1.5,0) coordinate (Xin)
                       -- ( 0.0,0)
                       -- ( 4.5,0) coordinate (Xout) node [right] {$x$};

        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (1.8, 0.9) node [midway,below] {$\Delta x$};
        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (2.8, 1.4) node [midway,right] {$\Delta y$};

        \draw [domain=-1:4,variable=\x,red,thick] plot({\x},{(\x)/2});

    \end{tikzpicture}
  % \caption{Linear function}
    \label{fig:linear}
    \end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT: It seems to have to do with an included preamble…**

I tried removing my preamble, and of course, the full-length document was screwed, but the box seemed to finally work. Can anyone spot anything in the below preamble that would interfere with the `insbox` macro?

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{bm,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,gensymb,esdiff,siunitx}
%===========================================================
%///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

% Universal command to recognise environments:

\makeatletter

\def\ifenv#1{
   \def\@tempa{#1}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@currenvir
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}

%%% \usepackage{xparse}
%%% 
%%% \ExplSyntaxOn
%%% \NewDocumentCommand{\newenvcommand}{ m m } % #1 = env name, #2 = command name
%%% {
%%%     \tl_if_exist:cF { g_envc_#1_list_tl } { \tl_new:c { g_envc_#1_list_tl } }
%%%     \tl_gput_right:cn { g_envc_#1_list_tl } { #2 }
%%%     \exp_args:Nc \newcommand { w envc_#1_\cs_to_str:N #2 }
%%% }
%%% \NewDocumentCommand{\checkenvcommands}{ }
%%% {
%%%     \tl_if_exist:cT { g_envc_\use:c {@currenvir} _list_tl }
%%%     {
%%%         \tl_map_inline:cn { g_envc_\use:c {@currenvir} _list_tl }
%%%         {
%%%             \cs_set_eq:Nc ##1 { envc_\use:c {@currenvir} _\cs_to_str:N ##1 }
%%%         }
%%%     }
%%% }
%%% \ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newenvcommand}{ m m } % #1 = env name, #2 = command name
  {
   \cs_if_exist:cF { g_envc_#1_list_tl } { \tl_new:c { g_envc_#1_list_tl } }
   \tl_gput_right:cn { g_envc_#1_list_tl } { #2 }
   \exp_after:wN \newcommand \cs:w envc_#1_\cs_to_str:N #2 \cs_end:
   % { Removing this line will cause Overleaf to make trouble }
  } 
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkenvcommands}{ }
  {
   \cs_if_exist:cT { g_envc_\use:c {@currenvir} _list_tl }
     {
      \tl_map_inline:cn { g_envc_\use:c {@currenvir} _list_tl }
        { \cs_set_eq:Nc ##1 { envc_\use:c {@currenvir} _\cs_to_str:N ##1 } }
     }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Underlines:

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{contour}

\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.8pt}
\contourlength{0.8pt}

\newcommand{\ul}[1]{%
  \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
  \llap{\contour{white}{#1}}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Boxes:

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{enhanced,boxrule=0.8pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,lifted shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{2mm}{0.1mm}{gray!60}}
\newtcbox{\eqbox}[3][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,colback=#2,colframe=#3,#1}
\newtcbox{\ndbox}[3][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,colback=#2,colframe=#3,#1}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{highlight/.style args={#1}{fill=#1,rounded corners=1.6pt,inner xsep=1ex,minimum height=1.5em},
%copy shadow={shadow xshift=0pt,shadow yshift=-0.4pt},
mylight/.style={highlight={red!30!yellow!40}{black!30!red!30!yellow}}}

%%% \usepackage{framed}
%%% \usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
%%% 
%%% \definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.827451,.827451,.827451}
%%% 
%%% \setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}

%---------------------------------
\newenvcommand{tcolorbox}{\ul}[1]{%
  \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
  \llap{\contour{shadecolor}{#1}}%
}
%---------------------------------

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Tables:

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}

%\newcommand\undefcolumntype[1]{\expandafter\let\csname NC@find@#1\endcsname\relax}
%\newcommand\forcenewcolumntype[1]{\undefcolumntype{#1}\newcolumntype{#1}}

%\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
%\newcolumntype{D}{>{\centering  \let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
%\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\raggedleft \let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering  \let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft \let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\newcolumntype{F}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering  \let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{>{\raggedleft \let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{\centering  \let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Q}[1]{>{\raggedleft \let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}b{#1}}

\setcellgapes{1.5pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.05em}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Colours:

\colorlet{backLightYellow}{red!30!yellow!30!white!30}
\colorlet{framLightYellow}{black!30!yellow!30}
\colorlet{backDarkYellow}{black!30!red!30!yellow}
\colorlet{framDarkYellow}{red!30!yellow!40}

\colorlet{backLightBlue}{cyan!30!blue!10}
\colorlet{framLightBlue}{black!30!cyan!40!blue!20}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage{titling}
%
%\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\null\mbox{}\vfill}
%\renewcommand\maketitlehookd{\vfill\null}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand\Item[1][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax  \item \else \item[#1] \fi
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

\newcommand\bs{\boldsymbol}
\renewcommand\bs[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.7em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
%===========================================================
%///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Excuse me. But have you the code into `insbox`? When I compile your code have many errors.

Comment: `insbox` is built into TeX. See Bernard's answer to my previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519963/183025

Comment: I added a working MWE to compare.

Comment: What also doesn't seem to work is `\begin{figure}Plain text\end{figure}` inside the box.

Comment: I did try that, and that's not the usage of `\InsertBoxL`. The usage is `\InsertBox{<lines down in paragraph>}{<Content of box>}`. I even added a case just for you to prove that this usage works. What doesn't work is your usage, which I indeed tested. I just didn't have time to comment because I was editing the post accordingly.

Comment: @ferahfeza Your usage is equivalent to `\InsertBox{<lines>}{<no content>} … {<some random unrelated group>}`. At least try your own code before recommending it to someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I've already said, do not try to insert a floating environment. To have a figure caption, insert  the tikzpicture in a `\parbox` of the relevant width and use `\captionof{figure}{...}`. Also, leave no blank line in the code of the tikzpicture. Last point: if TeX doesn't compute the correct number of shorter lines, you can use the number of supplementary shorter lines as an optional argument (and, contrary to the usual way, *last argument* of the command).

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxL{0}{%
\parbox{4.6cm}
{ \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.25in,y=.25in]
        \draw [<-, thick] (0, 4.2) coordinate (Yin) node [above] {$y$}
                       -- (0, 0.0)
                       -- (0,-1.2) coordinate (Yout);
        \draw [->, thick] (-1.5,0) coordinate (Xin)
                       -- ( 0.0,0)
                       -- ( 4.5,0) coordinate (Xout) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (1.8, 0.9) node [midway,below] {$\Delta x$};
        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (2.8, 1.4) node [midway,right] {$\Delta y$};
        \draw [domain=-1:4,variable=\x,red,thick] plot({\x},{(\x)/2});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
  \captionof{figure}{Linear function}
    \label{fig:linear}
}}[6]
\noindent\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It almost works. One problem seems to be that if you enter another paragraph after the first paragraph shown in your picture, that paragraph's first line is going to align with the first "Lorem". How do we solve this?

Comment: And what does that `[6]` do?

Comment: You should post an example showing this. With  `\lipsum[3]` as I have in my code, no such problem appears – I suppose some other code interacts with `\InsertBoxL`.

Comment: The optional `[6]` adds 6 shorter lines to the lines calculated  by TeX. Maybe in your real  case, they're not necessary?

Comment: I see with the lines now. However, it's odd that the paragraphs work fine in your MWE (and indeed when I run this exact code with nothing added but more paragraphs), but the following paragraphs suddenly indent themselves about those 4.6cm when I implement it in the middle of my other document. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is linked to your code. As you see, for simple text ltke \lipsum, there's no problem. Maybe some trickery you do  requires  being protected , but it's impossible to say without a code reproducing the problem.

Comment: I temporarily removed those extra lines to tackle one thing at a time. Check this screenshot out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT5on.png

Comment: Quite strange. Just using `\lipsum? Did you try putting \InsertBoxL and the  paragraph with first shorter lines inside a group?

Comment: Using `\lipsum` indeed. I tried with both `[1-3]` and just `[1]` three times. Here's two other screenshots, the first one with `[4]` extra short lines, and the second one with a line before the box as well. The `[4]` extra short lines does seem to have an influence on where the other paragraphs normalise. 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q57cG.png 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d325.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103227/discussion-between-bernard-and-matt).

Comment: I seem to have traced down what causes the problem. I'm going to mark your answer as the closing answer to this one, as it answered the very particular question in here. Then we'll move on to addressing this other problem in a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/526959/183025