# Annoying ghost column after parbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, parbox, insbox

So I've [previously asked a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/523947/183025) regarding `figure`s and `tikzpictures` inside boxes from the TeX macro package `insbox`. I got a working MWE, but implementing it in my full document made me realise another problem related to that solution.

Bernard told me to use `parbox` if I wanted a caption below my graph, but for some reason that very same `parbox` traces an entire column throughout the rest of the document with the width I specified.

Adding an enclosing group gets rid of the column for later paragraphs, however no for the paragraph that's wrapped around the box.

The weirdest thing of all is that removing my figure from the previous chapter about complex numbers removes the problem. What could this figure possibly do to paragraphs later in the document?

Does anyone have a clue as to what's happening?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Preamble brought into the MWE:

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{bm,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,gensymb,esdiff,siunitx}

%---------------------------------

% Universal command to recognise environments:

\makeatletter

\def\ifenv#1{
   \def\@tempa{#1}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@currenvir
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newenvcommand}{ m m } % #1 = env name, #2 = command name
  {
   \cs_if_exist:cF { g_envc_#1_list_tl } { \tl_new:c { g_envc_#1_list_tl } }
   \tl_gput_right:cn { g_envc_#1_list_tl } { #2 }
   \exp_after:wN \newcommand \cs:w envc_#1_\cs_to_str:N #2 \cs_end:
   % { Removing this line will cause Overleaf to make trouble }
  } 
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkenvcommands}{ }
  {
   \cs_if_exist:cT { g_envc_\use:c {@currenvir} _list_tl }
     {
      \tl_map_inline:cn { g_envc_\use:c {@currenvir} _list_tl }
        { \cs_set_eq:Nc ##1 { envc_\use:c {@currenvir} _\cs_to_str:N ##1 } }
     }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%---------------------------------

% Boxes:

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{enhanced,boxrule=0.8pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,lifted shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{2mm}{0.1mm}{gray!60}}
\newtcbox{\eqbox}[3][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,colback=#2,colframe=#3,#1}
\newtcbox{\ndbox}[3][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,colback=#2,colframe=#3,#1}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{highlight/.style args={#1}{fill=#1,rounded corners=1.6pt,inner xsep=1ex,minimum height=1.5em},
%copy shadow={shadow xshift=0pt,shadow yshift=-0.4pt},
mylight/.style={highlight={red!30!yellow!40}{black!30!red!30!yellow}}}

%---------------------------------
\newenvcommand{tcolorbox}{\ul}[1]{%
  \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
  \llap{\contour{shadecolor}{#1}}%
}
%---------------------------------

% Preamble over.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzset{font={\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\selectfont}}

\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\section{Complex Numbers}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=4cm,y=4cm]

        \draw [->, thick] (-1.25,0) coordinate (Xin)
                       -- ( 0.00,0)
                       -- ( 0.50,0) node[midway,highlight=white] {cos}
                       -- ( 1.25,0) coordinate (Xout);
        \draw [->, thick] (0,-1.20) coordinate (Yin)
                       -- (0, 0.00)
                       -- (0, 0.50) node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,yshift=2pt] {sin}
                       -- (0, 1.20) coordinate (Yout);

        \draw [ultra thick] circle (1);

        \foreach \t in {30,45,60,120,135,150}
        {
            \coordinate   (d\t) at (\t:1);
            \coordinate (c2d\t) at (\t:2);
        }
        \foreach \t in {30,45,60,120,135,150}
        {
            \coordinate   (n\t) at (360-\t:1);
            \coordinate (c2n\t) at (360-\t:2);
        }

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % 
        % Lables: [Degrees]

        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=1.1em,minimum width=3em] {$30\degree$} (d30);
        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=1.1em,minimum width=3em] {$45\degree$} (d45);
        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=1.1em,minimum width=3em] {$60\degree$} (d60);

        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=1.1em,minimum width=3em] {-$30\degree$} (n30);
        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=1.1em,minimum width=3em] {-$45\degree$} (n45);
        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=1.1em,minimum width=3em] {-$60\degree$} (n60);

        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=-1.1em,minimum width=3em] {$120\degree$} (d120);
        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=-1.1em,minimum width=3em] {$135\degree$} (d135);
        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=-1.1em,minimum width=3em] {$150\degree$} (d150);

        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=-1.1em,minimum width=3em] {-$120\degree$} (n120);
        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=-1.1em,minimum width=3em] {-$135\degree$} (n135);
        \draw [dashed, thick] (0,0) -- node[midway,sloped,highlight=white,xshift=-1.1em,minimum width=3em] {-$150\degree$} (n150);

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % 
        % Lables: [Tangent values]

        \coordinate (t30) at (intersection of 1,0--c2d60 and c2d30--d30);

        \draw [thick, dashed] (c2d60) -- (d60);
        \draw [thick, dashed]  (1,1)  -- (d45);
        \draw [thick, dashed]  (t30)  -- (d30);

        \draw [thick, dashed]
                      (c2d60) node[xshift=1.1em,yshift=-.1em] {$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1}$}
                   -- (1,1)   node[xshift=1.1em,yshift=.1em] {$\frac{1}{1}$}
                   -- (t30)   node[xshift=1.1em,yshift=.3em] {$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$}
                   -- (1,0);1

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % 
        % Lables: [Radians]

        \node [highlight=white] at ($(1,0)+(1.1em,1.1em)$) {$0$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(d30)+(1.1em,1.1em)$) {$\frac{\pi}{6}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(d45)+(1.1em,1.1em)$) {$\frac{\pi}{4}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(d60)+(1.1em,1.1em)$) {$\frac{\pi}{3}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(0,1)+(1.1em,1.1em)$) {$\frac{\pi}{2}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(d120)+(-1.1em,1.1em)$) {$\frac{2\pi}{3}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(d135)+(-1.1em,1.1em)$) {$\frac{3\pi}{4}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(d150)+(-1.1em,1.1em)$) {$\frac{5\pi}{6}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(-1,0)+(-1.1em,1.1em)$) {$\pi$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(n30)+(1.1em,-1.1em)$) {-$\frac{\pi}{6}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(n45)+(1.1em,-1.1em)$) {-$\frac{\pi}{4}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(n60)+(1.1em,-1.1em)$) {-$\frac{\pi}{3}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(0,-1)+(1.1em,-1.1em)$){-$\frac{\pi}{2}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(n120)+(-1.1em,-1.1em)$) {-$\frac{2\pi}{3}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(n135)+(-1.1em,-1.1em)$) {-$\frac{3\pi}{4}$};
        \node [highlight=white] at ($(n150)+(-1.1em,-1.1em)$) {-$\frac{5\pi}{6}$};

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % 
        % 

        \coordinate (s30) at (intersection of Yin--Yout and d30--d150);
        \coordinate (s45) at (intersection of Yin--Yout and d45--d135);
        \coordinate (s60) at (intersection of Yin--Yout and d60--d120);

        \coordinate (c60) at (intersection of Xin--Xout and d60--n60);
        \coordinate (c45) at (intersection of Xin--Xout and d45--n45);
        \coordinate (c30) at (intersection of Xin--Xout and d30--n30);

        \coordinate (c120) at (intersection of Xin--Xout and d120--n120);
        \coordinate (c135) at (intersection of Xin--Xout and d135--n135);
        \coordinate (c150) at (intersection of Xin--Xout and d150--n150);

        \coordinate (sn30) at (intersection of Yin--Yout and n30--n150);
        \coordinate (sn45) at (intersection of Yin--Yout and n45--n135);
        \coordinate (sn60) at (intersection of Yin--Yout and n60--n120);

        \fill ($(s30)-(2pt,.4pt)$) rectangle ($(s30)+(2pt,.4pt)$) node[left,xshift=-1ex] {$\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}$};
        \fill ($(s45)-(2pt,.4pt)$) rectangle ($(s45)+(2pt,.4pt)$) node[left,xshift=-1ex] {$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$};
        \fill ($(s60)-(2pt,.4pt)$) rectangle ($(s60)+(2pt,.4pt)$) node[left,xshift=-1ex] {$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$};
        \fill ($(c60)-(.4pt,2pt)$) rectangle ($(c60)+(.4pt,2pt)$) node[below,yshift=-1ex]{$\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}$};
        \fill ($(c45)-(.4pt,2pt)$) rectangle ($(c45)+(.4pt,2pt)$) node[below,yshift=-1ex]{$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$};
        \fill ($(c30)-(.4pt,2pt)$) rectangle ($(c30)+(.4pt,2pt)$) node[below,yshift=-1ex]{$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$};

        \fill ($(sn30)-(2pt,.4pt)$) rectangle ($(sn30)+(2pt,.4pt)$) node[left,xshift=-1ex] {-$\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}$};
        \fill ($(sn45)-(2pt,.4pt)$) rectangle ($(sn45)+(2pt,.4pt)$) node[left,xshift=-1ex] {-$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$};
        \fill ($(sn60)-(2pt,.4pt)$) rectangle ($(sn60)+(2pt,.4pt)$) node[left,xshift=-1ex] {-$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$};
        \fill ($(c150)-(.4pt,2pt)$) rectangle ($(c150)+(.4pt,2pt)$) node[below,yshift=-1ex]{-$\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}$};
        \fill ($(c135)-(.4pt,2pt)$) rectangle ($(c135)+(.4pt,2pt)$) node[below,yshift=-1ex]{-$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$};
        \fill ($(c120)-(.4pt,2pt)$) rectangle ($(c120)+(.4pt,2pt)$) node[below,yshift=-1ex]{-$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  % \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\section{Differential Equations}

This is a test paragraph above the box.

{%---------- begins enclosing group
\InsertBoxL{0}{%
\parbox{5cm}
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.25in,y=.25in]
        \draw [<-, thick] (0, 4.2) coordinate (Yin) node [above] {$y$}
                       -- (0, 0.0)
                       -- (0,-1.2) coordinate (Yout);
        \draw [->, thick] (-1.5,0) coordinate (Xin)
                       -- ( 0.0,0)
                       -- ( 4.5,0) coordinate (Xout) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (1.8, 0.9) node [midway,below] {$\Delta x$};
        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (2.8, 1.4) node [midway,right] {$\Delta y$};
        \draw [domain=-1:4,variable=\x,red,thick] plot({\x},{(\x)/2});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionsetup{font=compact}
    \captionof{figure}{Linear function}
    \label{fig:linear}
}}[4]
\noindent\lipsum[1]
}%---------- ends enclosing group

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Please note that your `\ifenv` macro includes a spurious space at its beginning, you should put a `%` after the opening brace.

Comment: Added a `%` after the `{`. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: Wouldn't `wrapfig` do better?

Comment: @egreg I already thought of that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/519959/183025 The conclusion was to use `insbox`.

Comment: But maybe that conclusion was specific to equations. I think you're on to something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to come  from the floating figure  just in the previous section. If you add  \clearpage at the end of the previous section, there's no problem, and you even can remove the enclosing braces.

*Unrelated*: you don't have to use the `[usenames]` option from `xcolor`, as it has been the default for quite a few years. Also: load `hyperref` as the last package (very few exceptions, most notable `cleveref` should be loaded  *after* hyperref).

............

```
\clearpage
\section{Differential Equations}

This is a test paragraph above the box.

\InsertBoxL{0}{%
\parbox{5cm}
{ \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.25in,y=.25in]
        \draw [<-, thick] (0, 4.2) coordinate (Yin) node [above] {$y$}
                       -- (0, 0.0)
                       -- (0,-1.2) coordinate (Yout);
        \draw [->, thick] (-1.5,0) coordinate (Xin)
                       -- ( 0.0,0)
                       -- ( 4.5,0) coordinate (Xout) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (1.8, 0.9) node [midway,below] {$\Delta x$};
        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (2.8, 1.4) node [midway,right] {$\Delta y$};
        \draw [domain=-1:4,variable=\x,red,thick] plot({\x},{(\x)/2});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{Linear function}
    \label{fig:linear}
}}[4]

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\noindent\lipsum[1]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes!!! This was actually the answer I was looking for. I didn't even think to clear the page, but I normally would do that between sections like these. Thanks a lot! Case closed. :D

Comment: And thanks for the tips regarding the packages. I will adjust accordingly. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want `wrapfig` rather than a plain TeX hack such as `insbox.tex`.

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\section{Differential Equations}

This is a test paragraph above the box.

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{5cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.25in,y=.25in]
        \draw [<-, thick] (0, 4.2) coordinate (Yin) node [above] {$y$}
                       -- (0, 0.0)
                       -- (0,-1.2) coordinate (Yout);
        \draw [->, thick] (-1.5,0) coordinate (Xin)
                       -- ( 0.0,0)
                       -- ( 4.5,0) coordinate (Xout) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (1.8, 0.9) node [midway,below] {$\Delta x$};
        \draw [thick] (2.8, 0.9) -- (2.8, 1.4) node [midway,right] {$\Delta y$};
        \draw [domain=-1:4,variable=\x,red,thick] plot({\x},{(\x)/2});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Linear function}
    \label{fig:linear}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That actually solved the problem. Thanks a lot :O